# Uploadify problem with Authentication Token and Html.AntiforgeryToken (plugin does not send cookies)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, uploadify, antiforgerytoken

Some time ago I had a problem with Uploadify plugin for which I did found a solution described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791724/getting-uploadify-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc/3816084#3816084).

The problem in that question was substantially due to the fact that Uploadify uses a flash plugin and the flash plugin does not share the authentication cookie with the server-side code.

The solution was to use a custom version of the Authorize attribute (the code was published within that answer).

The attribute [TokenizedAuthorize] was placed on the controller class as follow

```
[TokenizedAuthorize]
[CheckForActiveService]
public partial class DocumentController : BaseController
{
}
```

Some days ago I have added the `<%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>` inside the form and the 
`[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` to the action method as in the following sample:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual ActionResult Upload( HttpPostedFileBase fileData ) {
}
```

Anyway I am not anymore able to upload files to the server. Using the debugger I have been able to check that after the last line in the `TokenizedAuthorize` code

```
return base.AuthorizeCore( httpContext );
```

I get an exception handled by Elmah that says

```
System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException: invalid or not specified anti forgery token

in System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
in System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
in System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

This exception seems to confirm that the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute is being called... but I cant understand where is the issue with my code.

Any help?

**EDIT**:

Using the debugger I have checked the value of the `__RequestVerificationToken` form parameter and, as you can see, it is correctly populated with the value from `<%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>`

[image]

**EDIT 2**:

I can also confirm that if I comment the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` on the Post Action
everything works as expected

**EDIT 3**:

As the post function is an ajax call done by the uploadify plugin the AntiForgeryToken is added to the post parameters using a small js function as in the following code

```
$('#fileInput').uploadify({
    //other uploadify parameters removed for brevity
    scriptData: AddAntiForgeryToken({ AuthenticationToken: auth }),
});
```

where `AddAntiForgeryToken()` is a javascript function defined in my master page to support all the ajax post to the server

```
<%-- used for ajax in AddAntiForgeryToken() --%>
<form id="__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" action="#" method="post">
    <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
</form>

// Encapsulate the Anti Forgery Token fetching
AddAntiForgeryToken = function (data) {
    data.__RequestVerificationToken = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
    return data;
};
```

**EDIT 4**:

[Darin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) intuition is correct. The Uploadify script is not sending any cookie to the server and so the server cannot validate the AntiForgeryToken. How can I add the cookie inside the Uploadify scriptData section?

Comment: Actually is `System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException` with the description (trying to translate it exactly from italian) "AntiForgery Token not specified or invalid."

Comment: It's specified, so that means it's invalid. I would try to use the `<%=` tag instead of `<%:`, but thats just an idea ...

Comment: Actually I am not using `<%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>` to post the forgery token. The post is done through ajax so I am simply adding the forgery token inside the uploadify script. I am going to edit again the question to show you how...

Comment: Can you confirm that a cookie with the same value as the `__RequestVerificationToken` field is sent in the request?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to see the request using fiddler because the request does not get logged by this tool (this was also a problem I have stated at the end of this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791724/getting-uploadify-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc/3816084#3816084). Is there any other tool that I can use?

Comment: @Darin: I think you shoot the sheriff!!! I have checked with the debugger and realised that uploadify is not sending the cookie to the server together with the request. How can I add the cookie manually using jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must ensure that a cookie  with the same value as the `__RequestVerificationToken` field is sent in the request. Normally this cookie is emitted by the `Html.AntiforgeryToken()` and it must be done on the server because its value is encrypted with the server machine keys. If the request is performed by a Flash client I don't know whether it sends cookies. If this is not the case you will need to manually send it.

There's also something else that you should be aware of and which would throw the same exception although I don't think that it is applicable in your case but worth checking. When you use the `Html.AntiforgeryToken()` helper if there's a logged in user his username is part if the emitted cookie. If you then try to POST to a controller action decorated with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` it will verify that the currently logged in user is the same as the one when the cookie was emitted and if it isn't it will throw this exception. So what I have seen is people using the `Html.AntiforgeryToken()` to generate some html forms as an anonymous user and then using AJAX to log-in a user and once logged in the user submits the form - it will fail.

Comment: Thanks very much for helping Darin. All the points in your first paragraph are verified in my case. I will post details on the implementation when ready. thanks again

Comment: AFAIK, Flash has no access to the cookies and doesn't send them. At least Uploadify doesn't.

Comment: @ZippyV, hmm thanks for the precision. Are you sure about this as it seems a little surprising because I have seen this plugin used in authenticated areas of some sites and I wonder how does it work? If this is the case it could indeed explain the behavior. In fact here we are talking about a cookie marked with the HttpOnly flag so indeed it is not accessible in javascript but it is sent along an AJAX request, so I am a little surprised if Flash wouldn't send it, but I don't know because I don't have much experience with this technology.

Comment: I've posted a [question](http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/6771/cookie-with-uploadify/#Item_4) on the uploadify forum and @ZippyV is right: it does'nt send cookies.

Comment: On the other hand, if Uploadify was sending cookies, [the original problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791724/getting-uploadify-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc/3816084#3816084), where all this started, would never been present!

Comment: @Lorenzo, I am afraid you are out of luck here. The way antiforgery token works is that it expects this cookie and the classes are pretty internal and sealed to be able to customize this behavior unless you roll your own implementation from scratch. Also looking at Uploadify in more details it seems that it doesn't send cookies because of the nature of Flash and the only way to add additional data to the request is through the `scriptData` which doesn't help. So I think that you might need to remove this attribute from the POST action.

Comment: You're right Darin. Thanks again for yoru help. For now I have simply removed the attribute from the action but I think I will find another plugin to upload files :(