# MVC 3 Uploadify HTTP 302 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, uploadify

I have configuration problems with uploadify  (v.2.1.4) and my MVC 3 project. Here's the code which returns the HTTP 302 code.

```
        @{string auth = @Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] == null ? string.Empty : Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value;}

        $("#fileuploader").uploadify({
            uploader: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/uploadify.swf")',
            script: '@Url.Action("Upload", "Control")',
            scriptData: { token: "@auth" },
            fileDataName: 'file',
            buttonText: 'Upload file',
            multi: false,
            sizeLimit: 22222222222,
            simUploadLimit: 1,
            cancelImg: '@Url.Content("~/Images/uploadify-cancel.png")',
            auto: true,
            onError: function(event, queueID, fileObj, errorObj) {
                alert("Error!!! Type: [" + errorObj.type + "] Info [" + errorObj.info + "]");
            },
            onComplete: function (event, queueId, fileObj, response, data) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });

public class ControlController : Controller
{        
    [HttpPost]        
    public ActionResult Upload(string token, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var appData = Server.MapPath("~/app_data");
            var filename = Path.Combine(appData, Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
            file.SaveAs(filename);
        }
        return Json(true);
    }
}
```

1) The controller's action is not being fired

2) I've found that topic [Getting Uploadify to work with asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3791724/106616), but if I use that attribute to my controller, I see that "`AuthenticationToken`" is null (I'm logged in)

3) If I set the uploadify option '`method`' to '`post`' I get the `#2032 error`

### EDIT

The controller is the Admininistration controller, so I use that Attribute to it:

```
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {

        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        if (admin && !um.IsAdmin(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

which returns true. I've noticed, if I remove this attribute, the uploads started working. But I need that Attribute

Comment: @Andrew Barber: Hi Andrew!  Did you have any luck with this?  I'm running into the same exact issue.

Comment: @jaj it wasn't me; it was tony. But he was also sent a notification of your comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
it's help you.
var auth = "@(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]==null ? string.Empty : Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value)";
    var ASPSESSID = "@(Session.SessionID)";

    $("#uploadifyLogo").uploadify({
        ...
        'scriptData': { 'ASPSESSID': ASPSESSID, 'AUTHID': auth  }
    });
```

In Global.asax :

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      /* we guess at this point session is not already retrieved by application so we recreate cookie with the session id... */
        try
        {
            string session_param_name = "ASPSESSID";
            string session_cookie_name = "ASP.NET_SessionId";

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[session_param_name] != null)
            {
                UpdateCookie(session_cookie_name, HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[session_param_name]);
            }
            else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[session_param_name] != null)
            {
                UpdateCookie(session_cookie_name, HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[session_param_name]);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        try
        {
            string auth_param_name = "AUTHID";
            string auth_cookie_name = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[auth_param_name] != null)
            {
                UpdateCookie(auth_cookie_name, HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[auth_param_name]);
            }
            else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[auth_param_name] != null)
            {
                UpdateCookie(auth_cookie_name, HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[auth_param_name]);
            }

        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    private void UpdateCookie(string cookie_name, string cookie_value)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get(cookie_name);
        if (null == cookie)
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie(cookie_name);
        }
        cookie.Value = cookie_value;
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Set(cookie);
    }
```